# Incrementar valor JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

Tengo una tabla que muestra los valores de una select. A cada campo le acompaña un valor numerico que hace referencia a cada una de las lineas que la tabla tiene. Pero no soy capaz de hacer que se incrementen.

```
<tbody>
   <c:set var = "contador" value = "1" scope="page"/>
   <c:forEach items="${list}" var="actividad">
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">
            <c:set var="contador" value="${contador + 1}" scope="page"/>
         </th>
         <td>${actividad.actividad}</td>
         <td>${actividad.hora}</td>
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no soy capaz"? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento observado (excepción, se obtiene un valor distinto, etc.)?

Comment: El comportamiento es que no me saca nada en pantalla y me pone huecos vacios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que cuando haces `<c:set var = "contador" value = "1" scope="page"/>`, el valor de `1` se reconoce como una String.

Prueba con:

`<c:set var = "contador" value = "${1}" scope="page"/>`

**Update:**
    Ahora que sabemos que lo que quieres es mostrar el contador, puedes utilizar

`<c:out value = "${ }" />` y `varStatus = " "`:

```
   <c:forEach items="${list}" var="actividad" varStatus="numero">
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">
             <c:out value = "${numero.count}"/>
         </th>
         <td>${actividad.actividad}</td>
         <td>${actividad.hora}</td>
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
```

Si utilizas `${numero.index}` se comienza a contar desde `0`. Si utilizas `${numero.count}` se cuenta a partir de  `1`

Comment: He puesto los cambios que me has comentado pero sigo sin ser capaz de mostrar el contador en la pagina. https://imgur.com/a/2Ra32

Comment: Para mostrar el contador debes utilizar `<c:out />`

Comment: https://imgur.com/H8iP8Qd

Comment: Vale ya esta, gracias por la ayuda ;D

Comment: Se puede omitir esta linea:             <c:set var="contador" value="${numero.count}" scope="page"/>

Comment: Así es, puedes omitirla :-)